# Binary incompatibility after Cythoning on Mac M2

Tags: python, cython

I have a custom module that includes a `setup.py` file.

I run `python setup.py build_ext --inplace` in a Conda-built virtual environment on an M2 Mac.

I get the following runtime error during runtime (truncated):

`ValueError: libs.portfolio_manager.lib.adjustment.Adjustment size changed, may indicate binary incompatibility. Expected 56 from C header, got 24 from PyObject`

The directory structure is something like this:

```
/src
  /libs
    /portfolio_manager
      /lib/
        __init__.py
        adjustment.pyx
        adjustment.pxd
setup.py
```

Here are the relevant parts of the `setup.py` file:

```
import os
import versioneer
from setuptools import Extension, setup


class LazyBuildExtCommandClass(dict):
    """
    Lazy command class that defers operations requiring Cython and numpy until
    they've actually been downloaded and installed by setup_requires.
    """

    def __contains__(self, key):
        return key == "build_ext" or super(LazyBuildExtCommandClass, self).__contains__(
            key
        )

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        if key == "build_ext":
            raise AssertionError("build_ext overridden!")
        super(LazyBuildExtCommandClass, self).__setitem__(key, value)

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        if key != "build_ext":
            return super(LazyBuildExtCommandClass, self).__getitem__(key)

        import numpy
        from Cython.Distutils import build_ext as cython_build_ext

        # Cython_build_ext isn't a new-style class in Py2.
        class build_ext(cython_build_ext, object):
            """
            Custom build_ext command that lazily adds numpy's include_dir to
            extensions.
            """

            def build_extensions(self):
                """
                Lazily append numpy's include directory to Extension includes.
                This is done here rather than at module scope because setup.py
                may be run before numpy has been installed, in which case
                importing numpy and calling `numpy.get_include()` will fail.
                """
                numpy_incl = numpy.get_include()
                for ext in self.extensions:
                    ext.include_dirs.append(numpy_incl)

                super(build_ext, self).build_extensions()

        return build_ext


ext_modules = [
    Extension(
        name="src.libs.portfolio_manager.lib.adjustment",
        sources=["src/libs/portfolio_manager/lib/adjustment.pyx"],
        define_macros=[("NPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API", "NPY_1_7_API_VERSION")],
    ),
]


setup(
    ext_modules=ext_modules,
    cmdclass=LazyBuildExtCommandClass(versioneer.get_cmdclass()),
    package_data={
        root.replace(os.sep, "."): ["*.pyi", "*.pyx", "*.pxi", "*.pxd"]
        for root, dirnames, filenames in os.walk("src/libs/portfolio_manager")
        if "__pycache__" not in root
    },
)
```

Everything I read about this error has to do with an unsuppressed warning in a past version of Numpy.

What is this error caused by and how do I fix it?

Comment: Can you force a complete build and try again: `python setup.py build_ext --inplace --force`?

Comment: Same result, unfortunately. I also tried in a fresh virtual environment, too.